# A gentle textbook of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request

Is there a gentle textbook of complex analysis ? Something equivalent to Larson's Calculus (or Stewart's). I have Schaum's Outline of Complex Variables (Spiegel-Lipschutz), and it's not bad.

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of the "gentle" qualifier.  Low pre-requisites?  Well motivated proof strategies?  Worked exercises?

Comment: I found the book by Herb Silverman very pleasant to read for a first exposure to the subject.

Comment: I'm reminded of a footnote (no. 60) in [Sokal's infamous article](http://www.physics.nyu.edu/faculty/sokal/transgress_v2/transgress_v2_singlefile.html): "For a gentle introduction to set theory, see Bourbaki (1970)."

Answer (score 1):

Try H. A. Priestley's [*Introduction to Complex Analysis: Second Edition*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Introduction-Complex-Analysis-H-Priestley/dp/0198525621/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1384882607&sr=8-1&keywords=introduction+to+complex+analysis+h.a.+priestley), although I'm not sure that'd be everyone's idea of "gentle". I enjoyed it.

Answer (score 1):

To study complex analysis and its geometry, I recommend *Complex Analysis* by Lars Ahlfors.

Comment: This book is great, but not so gentle!